# Rakan and Xayah recall channel duration

Tags: league-of-legends

Rakan and Xayah have the ability to recall together where one starts recall and the other can join in. Will the 2nd champ who joins in at the last second get recalled to base instantly, or does the recall refresh?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Instantly**

**From the Wiki:**

*(which is usually reliable)*

> Lover's Leap: If either Rakan or Xayah  is  recalling, the other may move nearby and activate their own recall to join them. Both reach base at the time of which the initiator's recall ends.